# Mongoose find de objeto anidado no devuelve resultado

Tags: mongodb, sql, mongoose

Tengo un objeto anidado guardado en una collecion de mongodb usando mongoose.
Si hago una consulta con find(), me devuelve todos los registros de la colleccion pero cuando hago

```
db.drogas.find({identificacion: {estandarInterno: false}})
```

No me devuelve ningun resultado aunque existen registros que cumplen con esa condicion.

Este es el schema

```
const drogaSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    identificacion: {
            nombre: String,
            codigo: String,
            marca: String,
            nProducto: String,
            lote: String,
            CAS: String,
            codigoSenasa: String,
            estandarInterno: Boolean
    },
    informacion: {
            pureza: Number,
            humedad: Number,
            fecha: {
                    recepcion: Date,
                    vencimientoCertificado: Date,
            },
            cantidad: {
                    recibida: {masa: Number, unidad: String},
                    remanente: {masa: Number, unidad: String}
            },
            DLDC: {
                    libre: Boolean,
                    masaDL: Number,
                    masaDC: Number,
                    fDLDC: Number,
            },
            sectores: [String],
            rubros: [String],
            ubicacion: String,
            estado: String,
            observaciones: String
    },
    retesteos:{
            admiteRetesteo: Boolean,
            Retesteo: {
                    admite: Boolean,
                    numero: Number,
                    fecha:{
                            realizacion: Date,
                            vencimiento: Date,
                    }
            }
    }
```

});

Probe hacer distintos tipos de queries incluido el _id y cambian a findOne() pero nunca me devuelve un registro.
Tambien probe hacer las consultas directamente desde la terminal de mongo y tiene el mismo comportamiento.
Que error estoy comietiendo?

Comment: Puedes poner una muestra de tus datos?

Comment: Hola... Lo pude solucionar poniendo {"identificacion.estandarInterno": false }. Muchas gracias!!!